# Comparing Unix Timestamp to Date disregarding the time

Tags: php, mysql

There are a lot of duplicates about this question but, they didn't worked.

Here's the problem, I have two different time and same date which converted to timestamp that's stored on my database.

```
Timestamp 1 = 1376983800 (2013-08-20 15:30:00)
Timestamp 2 = 1376987400 (2013-08-20 16:30:00)
```

I have these two values that needed to compare with **date** disregarding their time.

**Visual Representation**

Let's say it should be `2013-08-20 = 2013-08-20`

**not**

`2013-08-20 15:30:00 = 2013-08-20 16:30:00`

Now, The question is how to do it using query?

These WHERE clause queries below doesn't work for me though.

```
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376983800)) = DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376987400))

WHERE DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376983800)) = DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376987400))

WHERE DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376983800)) = DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376987400))
```

A help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT columns
FROM table
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(stamp1)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(stamp2))
```

Also, all of your `WHERE` clauses above are equivalent to `WHERE TRUE` and will return all columns.

Also, to test what your `WHERE`s are actually looking at try doing things like:

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376983800)), DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376987400));
```

or

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376983800)), DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(1376987400))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Unixtime there's 86400 seconds per day, so there's no need to cast to DATE/TIMESTAMP:

```
WHERE ts1 - mod(ts1, 84000) = ts2 - mod(ts2, 84000)
```

or if ts1 is an INTEGER

```
WHERE ts1/86400 = ts2/86400
```